# Semantic commit type when replace images or texts?

Tags: git, git-commit

What semantic commit type is better to use, when I replace an image or text: feat, refactor or something else?

Comment: As there is no 'official' right and wrong answer, could you edit you question and explain a bit more about the sort of project you're working on, and any particularly methodologies you're trying to adhere to i.e. https://www.conventionalcommits.org/en/v1.0.0-beta.4/ ? If this is for a particular technology, e.g. Angular, please tag it.